# Creating graph-sun - how to write query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to write query in Cypher which creates graph-sun? I mean one node in the center, it has edges to each node, however another nodes (outside of the center) are not connected between themself.

Moreover, I would like each node has some random property, like `rank`. 
And then, how to write query which find `10` better (given rank) neighbors of center node?

Could anyone give something like that?

Comment: Hi @CypherFancy! If my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
create (center:Center),
(:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center),
(:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center),
(:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center),
(:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center),
(:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center),
(:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center),
(:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center)
```

to produce this graph:

[image: Graph]

Note the use of [rand()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/mathematical/numeric/#functions-rand) function to assign a random value to `rank` property in each node.

And to to get the top nodes based on `rank` property you can use (top 5, in this case):

```
match (:Center)<-[:LINKED_TO]-(n:Node)
with n order by n.rank desc limit 5
return n
```

---

**EDIT**

Here a more elegant (but complex) solution to create the "graph-sun" using the APOC Procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`. I'm using a parameter to determine the number of neighbors. The [docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) about apoc.periodic.iterate says:

> With apoc.periodic.iterate you provide 2 statements, the first outer
>   statement is providing a stream of values to be processed. The second,
>   inner statement processes one element at a time or with
>   iterateList:true the whole batch at a time.

So in the first statement I'm returning `number_of_n` items (using [range()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-range)) function. Then the second statement is executed `number_of_n` times, creating each neighbor.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"with range(0, {number_of_n} - 1) as items
unwind items as item
return item",
"merge (center:Center)
create (:Node{rank : rand()})-[:LINKED_TO]->(center)",
{params : {number_of_n:20}})
```

This query outputs a graph like:

[image: Graph generated using apoc.periodic.iterate]